Knock when opponent has 0 deadwood
What happens if player A knocks and player B has gin but hadn’t realized? Do they get the points plus the bonus gin points?

It's an undercut.
Player B wins the difference between the counts plus an undercut bonus.
From Pagat:

If the knocker did not go gin, and the counts are equal, or the
knocker's count is greater than that of the opponent, the knocker has
been undercut. In this case the knocker's opponent scores the
difference between the counts plus a 10 point bonus.


Note that in the situation described, player B does not have gin. He just has 0 deadwood.
In order to make a gin, a player must have 0 deadwood and to declare Gin during his turn.


Thank you, that’s super helpful. First time playing (it’s raining in Cyprus)

@Woodie - the best way to thank folks is to upvote (if you haven't) and accept the answer if you think it's helpful.
